# Why does view update but not the state variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm creating an app with React and I'm struggeling with state variables.
An example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(["inital"]);

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setA(["hello"]);
    }, 1000);
  
    setTimeout(() => {
      setA([...a, " world"]);
    }, 2000);
}, []);

return (
    <div>{a}</div>
  );
}
```

[Mutating State Functional Component Forked](https://%20https://codesandbox.io/s/mutating-state-functional-component-forked-v2vq33?file=/src/App.tsx)

**The result in the view is:**

> 0 sec: initial
>
> 1 sec: hello
>
> 2 sec: initial world

What I expected:

> 0 sec: initial
>
> 1 sec: hello
>
> 2 sec: hello world

It's confusing because the state `hello` was definitely set like you can see in the view. Why does `a` has the value `initial` in the second timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setA([...a, " world"]);` is taking the value at the time when you create your function (before the wait, so before the first `setTimeout` callback is called). At this time the value is "initial"

If you want it to update properly you could use

```js
setA(prev => [...prev, " world"]);
```

This will get the value of the state when the `setA` function is actually called and give you the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to closure -
At the time of creation, the line `setA([...a, " world"])` still refers to the initial `a`.
You can solve this by a second `useEffect` which will have `a` as a dependency, but then you'll probably run into an infinite loop, so you might have to include a condition.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setA(["hello"]);
    }, 1000);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (a.length === 1) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setA([...a, " world"]);
        }, 2000);
    }
}, [a]);

    
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and suggested solution, @raz-ezra!